# How to parse several XML file into several CSV file?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, csv, elementtree

I parsed XML file using this code that works for a single xml input to single csv output. I tried using glob to work on several input and also several csv output but I know this is not correct.

```py
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import csv

for file in glob.glob('./*.xml'):
    with open(file) as f:
        tree = et.parse(f)
        nodes = tree.getroot()

        with open(f'{f[:-4]}edited.csv', 'w') as ff:
            cols = ['dateTime','x','y','z','motion','isMoving','stepCount','groupAreaId','commit']
            nodewriter = csv.writer(ff)
            nodewriter.writerow(cols)
            for node in nodes:
                values = [ node.attrib.get(kk, '') for kk in cols]
                nodewriter.writerow(values)
```

How should I change to get several csv output?

Comment: Did you mean to use `with open(f'{file[:-4]}edited.csv', 'w') as ff:` ? Currently you are using the file handle for the filename.

Comment: Got your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently using a file handle to form your output filename. Instead of `f` use `file` as follows:

```
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import csv

for file in glob.glob('./*.xml'):
    with open(file) as f:
        tree = et.parse(f)
        nodes = tree.getroot()

        with open(f'{file[:-4]}edited.csv', 'w') as ff:
            cols = ['dateTime','x','y','z','motion','isMoving','stepCount','groupAreaId','commit']
            nodewriter = csv.writer(ff)
            nodewriter.writerow(cols)
            for node in nodes:
                values = [ node.attrib.get(kk, '') for kk in cols]
                nodewriter.writerow(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list of file names then write xml files there. If output files ar already in the derectory then using glob you can get names. If the files is not exist the below code will create using given file name

```
csvFileNames = ['outputfile1.csv', 'outputfile2.csv']
for file in csvFileNames:
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        wtr = csv.writer(f)
        wtr.writerows( [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]) # write what you want
```

to get XML filenames from directory you can try below code :

```
from os import listdir
filenames = listdir('.') # here dot is used because script and csv files are in the same directory, if XML files are in other directory then set the path inside listdir
xmlFileNames = [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith( ".xml" ) ]

# get xml file names like this, xmlFileNames = ["abc.xml", "ef.xml"]
resultCsvFileNameList = [fname.replace(".xml", ".csv") for fname in xmlFileNames ]
```

Comment: but if I have thousands of csv files to write, is there any easier than mentioning the csv filename one by one?

Comment: you don't have to write filename manually,  using glob you can collect filenames

Comment: thanks for the edit, but my problem is I need to create .csv file from xml file, and obviously the csv file is not existed yet. that is why I wonder how to automatically create .csv file with same filename as xml.